# Angular ajax success msg

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Who should show the success msg and redirect the user. Currently On success the service shows success msg and redirects the user or should that be done by ctrl. Question is regarding separation of concern.

**Ctrl**

```
$scope.save = function (entry) {
    MyService.save(entry);
};
```

**Service**

```
$http.post('/groups', data)
     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        Notiy('saved');
        RouteFactory.back();
     })
     .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        Notiy('Failed');
     });
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackoverflow.com

Comment: it's not a code review its dealing with how do do a thing in angular

Comment: I don't actually see a question in there at all...

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic and opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @S0lll0s answer i went with a cleaner yet simpler solution of  promises

**Service**

```
        var request = $http({
            method: "delete",
            url: '/group/' + id
        });
        return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
```

**Controller**

```
        MyService.save(data)
                .then(function () {
                    RouteFactory.back();
                }, function () {
                    Notify('failed');
                });
        };
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you pass a callback argument?

```
$http.post('/groups', data)
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    callback(null, data);
    RouteFactory.back();
  })
  .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    callback(status, data);
    Notiy('Failed');
  });
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.save = function (entry) {
  // for example show loading indicator here
  MyService.save(entry, function (err, data) {
    // hide it again here
  });
};
```